# jQuery/AJAX routing with JSON

Tags: json, jquery

Hello I am creating a simple website with just HTML/CSS and Javascript because I can not use ServerSide languages ( server doesn't support them) and now I am creating the routing of my website with jQuery/AJAX and even with my low Javascript knowledge I managed to create the most. But I cannot find out how to get the right index from my JSON file.

the JSON file is as follows:

```
{
  "home": {
      "pattern": "/home",
      "target":  "home.html"
  },
  "webshop": {
      "pattern": "/webshop",
      "target":  "webshop.html"
  }
}
```

and the jQuery that I used in my index.html is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//wacht op laden pagina

$.ajax({
  url: 'routing.json',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    // do stuff with response.
    var nav = $('.nav_menu ul');

    $.each(response, function(route) {
        for(var i=0;i<route.length;i++){
        console.log("route["+i+"] is =>"+route[i]);
    }
        nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + route + '">' + route + '</a></li>');

    });

  }

});

});
</script>
```

Now is the problem that in my jQuery part I don;t know how to create the right links ( see the route )

```
nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + route + '">' + route + '</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you have a further `for` loop in the `$.each()`. It is not necessary. Instead, try

```
$.each(response, function(id,route) {
    nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + route.target + '">' + route.pattern + '</a></li>');
});
```

Comment: Do you know by accident also how to load the right link into a div? I tried $(".main_content").load(this.target); but no result

Comment: Create another question, lets not mix stuff up

Answer (score 1):

Example Json

```
 "yyyList": [
        {
          "Id": "1",
          "Name": "aaaa "
        }, {
          "Id": "2",
          "Name": "bbb "
        }, {
          "Id": "6",
          "Name": "ccc "
        }, {
          "Id": "7",
          "Name": "ddd "
        } ]


$.ajax({
              url: "URL",
               //data: "",
               type: "GET",
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function (data) {            
               $.each(data.YYYList, function () {
                  $('#state').append('<'li value='+this.Id+'>'+this.Name+'<'/li>');
               });
            }
        })
```

$('#state') ---> gives the same id for UL tag in HTML Please make correct it option syntax

Answer (score 0):

You're treating your object like a JavaScript array.  Why not work with an array instead?

```
[
 { "route": "home", "pattern": "/home", "target": "home.html" },
 { "route": "webshop", "pattern": "/webshop", "target": "webshop.html" }
]

$.each(response, function(i, routeInfo) {
    nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + routeInfo.route + '">' + routeInfo.route + '</a></li>');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, the answer from Abhilash keeps your structure.  Your problem was that your `$.each()` signature didn't account for the first parameter being the index and the second being the item in the collection.  I was assuming you needed the name of the route, not the target, so that's why I answered the way I did.  If you don't need it, then Abhilash's answer is better (IMHO) as it keeps your structure.

Comment: hmm but there is no difference right? I found this way with JSON much better since it looked organized

Comment: I mistyped the signature for the `$.each` function....the first parameter is the index, the second is the item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you treat it more like an array, but in fact it is an object. Try this:

```
$.each(response, function(route) {
    console.log(response[route])
    nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + response[route].target + '">' + response[route].pattern + '</a></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a JSON response you could turn that into an actual object using `$.parseJSON()`.

Try something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'routing.json',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    // do stuff with response.
    var nav = $('.nav_menu ul');

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    for(var ele in obj){
      nav.append('<li><a href="index.html/#/' + obj[ele].target + '">' + obj[ele].pattern + '</a></li>');
    }

  }

});
```